# Article avant les noms de sociétés

Tags: articles, absence-d-article

Pourriez-vous me dire quand on met un article devant un nom de société et quand on ne le met pas?

Autant que je sache, on dit `Google`, `Facebook` mais `la SNCF`. Est-ce qu'une règle existe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si le nom de la société ou de l'organisation est aussi un nom commun, ou peut se décomposer dans une expression qui commence normalement par un article, on peut le mettre, mais ce n'est pas systématique.

La SNCF, c'est la **S**ociété **n**ationale des **c**hemins de **f**er français.

On dit aussi le PS (le parti socialiste), le PC (communiste), *Les Républicains*, ***l***'ONU (l'Organisation des Nations unies), ***la*** Croix Rouge, ***la*** CIA (agence), **la** BBC (corporation), **la** RTBF (radio télévision belge francophone) et on disait ***le*** KGB, ***la*** TWA, ***la*** Sabena (Société anonyme belge d'exploitation de la Navigation aérienne), ***la*** régie Renault, ***l***'ORTF (Office de radiodiffusion télévision française)...

Il y a longtemps, on disait *la SFR* (Société française de Radiotéléphones) mais on n'utilise plus d'article aujourd'hui.

On s'en passe parfois aussi pour la SNCF, comme dans une publicité mémorable, surtout grâce à sa parodie par les Nuls qui disait :

> SNCF, c'est possible

La tendance est d'avoir des noms de sociétés sans article, probablement parce que ce sont aussi des noms de marques, donc des noms propres, et que les noms propres ne prennent généralement pas d'article. Une autre raison est que ça « passe » mieux à l'international...

Comment: Bon, j'aillais répondre, mais une réponse suffira amplement. Voici où j'en étais rendu, si vous voulez en ajouter des bribes à votre réponse: «On dit aussi la CSN (Confédération des syndicats nationaux), l’ONU (Organisation des Nations unies, l’UMP (Union pour un Mouvement Populaire).»

Comment: Exemples de sigles utilisés sans articles: HP, ING, IBM. Les sociétés de télévision et radio: TF1, RTL, RMC, TV5 ... (mais on continue de dire la RTBF en Belgique...) . Pas trouvé d'équivalent en France ou autre pays francophone, mais je constate aussi qu'en Belgique, on utilise les noms de parti sans article s'ils forment un acronyme dont plus personne ne connait la signification (ex: on dit "Chez Défi", Défi signifiant "Démocrate fédéraliste indépendant")